# How to get data from this form with Curl?

Tags: php, curl, post, http-post

I have a page on [this link](https://www.sefaz.ba.gov.br/scripts/cadastro/cadastroBa/consultaBa.asp) and this send a parameter via POST form. This paramenter have a name **CGC** and the value for test is **05262967000165**. I need to get content of this page with curl but I tried without success.

Can someone help me get the html from this page? Thanks

```
<?php

$cr = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.sefaz.ba.gov.br/scripts/cadastro/cadastroBa/consultaBa.asp");
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "CGC=05262967000165");

$retorno = curl_exec($cr); 
curl_close($cr); 

echo $retorno;
```

Comment: so you want to send curl request to the first link, and the first link should redirect to the second one? what is the problem now? do you get an error? do you get a wrong response? could you please explain your problem with more details?

Comment: @FatemehMajd I need just that curl work. I modified question.